# Show {$x^k$}$_{k\geq 0}$ is complete in $L^2[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I'm thinking of using the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem where the span of monomials is dense in the continuous functions.

Comment: That works fine.

Comment: I'm not too sure however to move past that step. Is the continuous function dense in integrable functions?

Comment: polynomials are $L^\infty$-dense in $C[a,b]$ and so $L^2$-dense in $C[a,b]$. $C[a,b]$ is $L^2$-dense in $L^2[a,b]$.